# what's wrong with this simple Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have two c files: a4.c and a4Defs.h

The code compiles fine: gcc -o a4 a4.c a4Defs.h

I've build this simple makefile but when I do a 'make' I get this error:

```
gcc -c a4Defs.h
gcc -c a4.c
gcc -o a4 a4.o a4Defs.o
gcc: error: a4Defs.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [a4] Error 1
```

What's wrong with my makefile?

```
a4: a4.o a4Defs.o
    gcc -o a4 a4.o a4Defs.o

a4.o:   a4.c a4Defs.o
    gcc -c a4.c

a4Defs.o:   a4Defs.h
    gcc -c a4Defs.h

clean:
    rm -f *.o a4
```

Comment: What files do you actually have? acDefs.c or a4Defs.h? Description says .h, makefile says .c

Comment: I meant a4Defs.h -- sorry.  I changed it, and updated with the new error message I get.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well for a start you shouldn't be trying to compile .h files. They are included by the .c files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a4Defs.h` is a header file not a `.c` file so there is no meaning in compiling it.

your make file should look something like this

```
a4: a4.o
    gcc -o a4 a4.o

a4.o:   a4.c a4Defs.h
    gcc -c a4.c


clean:
    rm -f *.o a4
```